# Filter a spark dataset with spark sql

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

could you please help me to solve this case?
I have two DataSets and I want to perform this query on spark.

My first dataset **AccountsByContraclines**

| accountid | startdate | enddate | cancellationdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0011t00000MY9aXAAT | 2021-02-25 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-24 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0013X00002UM0wtQAD | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000MY6JoAAL | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000MY8x6AAD | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0011t00000RmNtiAAF | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |
| 0013X00003N89dFQAR | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 | NULL |

And my second ds **notBucomContracts** :

| accountid | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0011t00000MY6JoAAL | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 |
| 0011t00000MY8x0AAD | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 |
| 0011t00000RmNtiAAF | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 |
| 0013X00003N89dFQOR | 2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000 |

I tried to perform this query by using SQL expressions but it doesn't run

```
notBucomContracts.createOrReplaceTempView("bucomContracts")
  AccountsByContraclines.createOrReplaceTempView("AccountsByContraclines")

      val filtered = AccountsByContraclines
          .select("accountid", "startdate", "enddate")
          .filter(
            " accountid not in (select r2.accountid from bucomContracts r2 " +
              "where(r2.startDate < cast(cast(year(AccountsByContraclines.startdate) as string) ||'-' ||" +
              " cast(month(AccountsByContraclines.startdate) as string) || '-01' as date) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH " +
              " and (r2.endDate is null or r2.endDate >= AccountsByContraclines.startDate)  ) " +
              "   or    (r2.startDate > cast(cast(year(AccountsByContraclines.startdate) as string) || " +
              "'-' || cast(month(AccountsByContraclines.startdate) as string) || '-01' as date)" +
              " - INTERVAL '1' MONTH and r2.startDate < AccountsByContraclines.startDate))")
```

How can I use aliases in the right way or how can I perform the query programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add some info like what kind of rows you are trying to filter and  expected output.

Comment: well , the output i want to have is a new ds with this columns **"accountid", "startdate", "enddate"**.
And i'm trying to filter **AccountsByContraclines**  to eleminate rows when  there is any accountid between the first day of the previous month and the startdate.